# How to hide and show elements with animation and easing effects

Tags: jquery

I have an N level menu structure where I have to hide the child menus in all levels at first and show them on hover of the parent menu..I had been trying this I got to hide all the children and show them on click but the issue is when I click on other parent the menu which is previuosly opened has to be closed and its child should be in hidden state if I go click that menu again and I want some easing and animation effects while opening and closing the menu it should work as a toggle.

This is what I have been trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("li").children('ul').hide();
$("li a").click(function(){
$(this).next('ul').toggle();            
$(this).parent().siblings('li').children('ul').hide();
```

here is [the](http://jsfiddle.net/kKsXz/) js fiddle of what i am trying to do

i should not use any classes and or any attributes on the menu only the top level ul has the class remaining every thing should be done in jquery i need the easing and animation part to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some animations using [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/6u4LJ/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").children('ul').hide();
    $("li a").click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').find('ul').hide();
        $(this).next('ul').slideDown();            
        $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();           
    });     
});
```

You could also do this fairly easily by using CSS3 transitions with a class on the active list item.

**EDIT:** I understand now, try adding this to hide all inner lists when you click to open one.

```
$(this).next('ul').find('ul').hide();
```

Comment: but my issue is not fixed at....all the childs are in open state once i open them go to other parent and if i come back there all the levels are in open state

Comment: Updated, i think I understand your issue now.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Tyriar answer, this is how to use the JQueryUI easing effects : http://jqueryui.com/effect/#easing

http://jsfiddle.net/6u4LJ/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").children('ul').hide();
    $("li a").click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').animate({
            height: "show"
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutBounce');
        $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('ul').animate({
            height: "hide"
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutBounce');
    });
});
```

Comment: but my issue is not fixed at....all the childs are in open state once i open them go to other parent and if i come back there all the levels are in open state